# SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: Unable to connect to server ) Error 103?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, microsoft-cluster-server

Does anyone know how to make the second SQL instance Agent working on the same MSCS SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster?

In the clustered SQL Server service instance2 i have assigned the same service account to start all of the other service in for instance1

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SQLAgent$LYNC
Date:          26/08/2011 12:40:46 PM
Event ID:      103
Task Category: Service Control
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SQLNode1-VM.DOMAIN.com
Description:
SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: Unable to connect to server 'SQLNode1-VM\Instance1'; SQLServerAgent cannot start).
```

I always get the above error, therefore I cannot proceed in adding the secondary node for my second DB instance.

Comment: Can't this be done using Configuration Manager?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm stuck in this problem when I tried to add he secondary Node to the cluster group.

Comment: did you mean we can not start Sql server agent with Win7 and SQL Server 2008 ??